# Comparing two arrays in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have two similar arrays, one for tracking the qualifications of employees, one for tracking the qualifications required for jobs. I wish to compare the two, and return TRUE if the employee is qualified for the job. Here's how my array's look:

```
Employee | Qualification1 | Qualification2 | Qualification3 
Dave     | 1              | 0              | 1
Bob      | 0              | 1              | 1

Job      | Qualification1 | Qualification2 | Qualification3 
Job1     | 0              | 1              | 1
Job2     | 1              | 0              | 1
```

The problem is that the data in the array and the size of the array are likely to change as new jobs are added etc. The arrays are both defined using an =OFFSET formula so they will change size with the data. What I am missing is some way to compare every value for a specific job to every value in a row in the other array. This just needs to output to a cell to tell me if each employee in turn is qualified (I plan on using this information in another formula afterwards). Also bear in mind it doesn't matter if the employee is overqualified for the job, so long as they also have the qualifications required for it.

If anybody has any ideas please let me know, I've been looking at this for like 3 days now

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to compare is to use the `=Concatenate()` formula and to compare the output string.

If the string is the same, the arrays are equal.

---

Concerning the qualifications, a possible solution is to go through some binary mathematics. The Excel formula for decimal to binary is quite easy - `=DEC2BIN(11)`:

- assign values like this 1,2,4,8,16 (2^n);
- sum the values. E.g. 1 + 2 + 8 for the user with qualifications on the 1st,2nd and 4th position;
- save the sum as binary;
- then, if you want to check whether a qualification is possessed by the user, check the binary code and compare. E.g. `1011` is `11`. And it shows, that the user has qualifications 1+2+8. And lacks qualification `4`, thus there is a `0`;

Comment: Is this fulfilling below requirement? `Also bear in mind it doesn't matter if the employee is overqualified for the job, so long as they also have the qualifications required for it.`

Comment: @SuraniMatharaarachchi - it gives the basics only :)

Comment: @Vityata - Thanks for the answer, I tried similar approaches but the problem then comes with dealing with the exception cases where the employee has more qualifications than required, that bit of the formula has so many variables in it that I struggled to wrap my head around it, let alone code it.

Comment: @JakePierrepont - you can probably use `=COUNTIFS()` and count whether the cells contain `1`. Or `=SUMIFS()`.

Comment: @Vityata - similar problem there, you can tell that they have more qualifications than required but not that they have the specific ones that are required and more instead of just a load of unrelated qualifications

Comment: @JakePierrepont - you can solve this through some binary tricks. E.g., set values for the qualifications like this - 1,2,4,8,16,32, 64.... Then to make sure that someone has qualification 8 and any other, he should be in the range of 8 to 15. For qualification 4, the range is 4 to 7 etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was close to giving up :)

Comment: @JakePierrepont - welcome.  The binary maths is really useful, if you know where to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample data starts @ A1. Where A1 = Employee and A5 = Job, you may try :

```
G1 = Job1
H1 = Job2
F2 = Dave
F3 = Bob

G2  

 =IF((IF(INDEX($B$5:$B$7,MATCH(G$1,$A$5:$A$7,0))=0,1,IF(INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH($F2,$A$1:$A$3,0))*INDEX($B$5:$B$7,MATCH(G$1,$A$5:$A$7,0))=1,1,0))*IF(INDEX($C$5:$C$7,MATCH(G$1,$A$5:$A$7,0))=0,1,IF(INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH($F2,$A$1:$A$3,0))*INDEX($C$5:$C$7,MATCH(G$1,$A$5:$A$7,0))=1,1,0))*IF(INDEX($D$5:$D$7,MATCH(G$1,$A$5:$A$7,0))=0,1,IF(INDEX($D$1:$D$3,MATCH($F2,$A$1:$A$3,0))*INDEX($D$5:$D$7,MATCH(G$1,$A$5:$A$7,0))=1,1,0)))=1,"Qualified","No")
```

Select G2 and drag until H3. Done.

In index/match, the source/ref range is always adjustable. Set it once, and just drag it.

Hope that helps. (: